# Error al intentar normalizar datos

Tags: r

Estoy normalizando un archivo csv con R.

```
datos <- read.csv2("Z.EMR.csv")
normalize <- function(x) { return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}
```

En esta linea me sale el siguiente error

```
datos_norm <- as.data.frame(lapply(datos, normalize))
```

> Error in Summary.factor(c(1793L, 1778L, 1791L, 1868L, 1794L, 1797L,
>   775L,  :    ‘min’ not meaningful for factors

Los datos que estan en el csv tienen este formato

```
600   21.253.671   742.868.110.810.811   24.306.558  223.452.149.180.328
```

Cualquier ayuda desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más probable es que una de las columnas sea categórica. Puedes poner un `if` en la función para que, en el caso que la columna sea `factor` no realice ninguna operación:

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
  if(is.factor(x)) {return(x)}
  (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))}
data.frame(lapply(datos, normalize))
```

Answer (score 1):

El error se debe fundamentalmente por que alguna de las columnas es un  `factor` y no un dato numérico. Este sería un ejemplo:

```
normalize <- function(x) {return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))}
v <- factor(rnorm(10))
normalize(v)

 Error in Summary.factor(c(9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 1L, 10L), na.rm = FALSE) : 
  ‘min’ not meaningful for factors
```

Ya la primer función `min()` no tiene sentido con `factor`. Acá se abren algunas posibilidades:

#### 1. Efectivamente el dato es un factor y no corresponde normalizarlo

Puedes condicionar la aplicación de `normalize` o modificar `normalize` para que tenga en cuenta que hacer si le llega un `factor`, pero claramente no deberíamos aplicar esta función en las columnas que son `factor`, entonces lo ideal para mi gusto, es aplicar `normalize` solo en la columnas que corresponda y no en el `data.frame` completo. Con `names(datos)[-sapply(df, is.factor)]` obtenemos los nombres de las columnas que no son factores, por lo que podemos hacer un subset del `data.frame` original y aplicar `normalize` en él:

```
lapply(datos[ ,names(datos)[-sapply(df, is.factor)], drop=FALSE], normalize)
```

#### 2. Aún siendo un factor queremos normalizarlo

Convertir un `factor` a numérico (siempre que tenga sentido hacerlo), se hace mediante `as.numeric(as.character(x))`, tu `lapply` podría expresarse así:

```
lapply(datos, function(x) {if(is.factor(x)){as.numeric(as.character(x))}else{normalize(x)}})
```

Nota: llegado el caso, mejor que convertir el `factor` en un numérico, es analizar por que la lectura del `csv` produce un `factor` y corregir esto.